# Resolve an Access Violation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Sort the array of strings in alphabetic order.

I have used selection sort with the `strcmp()` library function

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

main()
{
    int min;
    char *temp;
    char *str[] = {"Java", "Ruby", "Pyhton", "JavaScript", "JavaScrikt"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(str[min], str[j]) > 0)
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(str[i], str[min]) != 0)
        {
            strcpy(temp, str[i]);
            strcpy(str[i], str[min]);
            strcpy(str[min], temp);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an Access Violation. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Tangential to your crashing problem — Note that the standard uses `#include <stdio.h>` etc for standard headers, and you should do the same.  Also, you should be using `int main(void)` to define `main()`; what you've written is pre-standard style, still allowed by the first standard (C90) but not supported by the standard at any time in the current millennium (C99 and later require the return type stated explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialise temp. Instead of `char *temp;` put `char temp[16]`.

Comment: While it works in this case, this isn't very robust. Adding a string with more than 15 characters will break things.

Comment: @ThomasJager Yes indeed. That's just to some things rolling. The author may decide to set the size of temp to an appropriate value either by finding the max string length from the array or just use a defined value and check for overflows.

Comment: What @Robert 's answer is saying is also true. You should perhaps consider memory allocation or preinitialise a large 2D array of chars to have room to swap strings. Or to keep things simple, just create another int array with the sorted "indices" of the string array.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you turn on all compiler warnings. When I compile your code under Linux with `-Wall` (all warnings turned on), I get:

```
robert@saaz:~$ gcc -Wall himi.c
himi.c: In function ‘main’:
himi.c:22:13: warning: ‘temp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             strcpy(temp, str[i]);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

An uninitialized pointer is always good for an access violation (or segmentation fault, on Unix), as you're trying to access some random memory that isn't yours, and the operating system slaps you on the wrist (i.e., terminates your misbehaving program).

That said, when you sort strings, you usually don't `strcpy` the strings around in memory, you just switch around the pointers. This is much faster, as you only need to modify pointers. It also avoids crashes with different string lengths: your code would try to copy the "JavaScript" (10 characters) into "Java" (4 characters). Writing in memory areas you're not supposed to write can crash your program (if you're lucky) or you just overwrite other variables and notice only much later (have fun debugging that).

Here's your updated code. I also added code to print the sorted array.

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
    int min;
    char *temp;
    char *str[] = {"Java", "Ruby", "Pyhton", "JavaScript", "JavaScrikt"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(str[min], str[j]) > 0)
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(str[i], str[min]) != 0)
        {
            temp = str[i];
            str[i] = str[min];
            str[min] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `strcpy()` tries to modify string literals; that causes problems too (often access violation problems(.